# Can I use multiple different commands for a single file type with the Code Runner extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ -Wall -Wextra -O2 -std=c++14 $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"
},
```

Coderunner has a command to run .cpp code, but if I want to use another command, such as adding " < input.txt", I would have to go to settings.json to change it. Is there a way to set up multiple commands on VS Code for a single kind of file so I can just simply switch without having to change settings.json?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're changing the value of [`code-runner.executorMap`](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner#configuration) in a workspace's `.vscode/settings.json` file? But you can just change it in you user settings.json file (use `Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)` in the command palette), and that should apply to all your workspaces then by default. See also https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings.